# Using right-align on a group of two label controls in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have my application running, but for some reason my two label controls will not align the way I want.

The application converts one length to another, depending on the selection made in a combo box. 
There these controls, left to right, top to bottom as shown:

ComboboxLabel, Combobox
LabelOriginLength, TextBoxOriginLength
LabelConvertedLength, TextboxConvertedLength (read only)

ButtonCalculate, ButtonExit

The load event handler for the form sets the combo box to select the 0 index item in the list.

There is a handler for SelectedIndexChanged. This handler finds the correct origin and destination length labels, stored in a rectangular array as follows:

```
        string[,] conversionData = new string[6, 3] { 
        { "Miles", "Kilometers", "1.6093" }, 
        { "Kilometers", "Miles", ".6214" },
        { "Feet", "Meters", ".3048" },
        { "Meters", "Feet", "3.2808"},
        {"Inches", "Centimeters", "2.54"},
        {"Centimeters", "Inches", ".3937"}
    };
```

That said. Any time the user changes the value of the combobox, the labels should change.

As such, I selected the 2 label controls in a group, and clicked the Align Rights button on the toolbar. This should align them correctly, even after the labels change from the handler, yes?

Well, they do NOT line up correctly, as shown here:
[image: screenshot here].

As an added note- grouping them and using the left align button on the toolbar DOES work properly, as shown here:
[image: shown here].

What have I done wrong?!

Comment: Set Autosize to false, make them large enough and if you want to set TextAlign.. (Note that Autosize was was confused you! It is true by default and makes the Labesl (etc) change their size with the content)

Comment: Thanks @TaW, worked out just as I wanted.